# Specializing trailing return type based on std::begin() return type

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, c++11, sfinae, trailing-return-type

As an excercise, I want to create a generic templated summing function for containers. While my goal is well achieved with "nested template" overloads, I want to write a function which is based solely on `std::begin()`/`std::end()`, to allow it to work on everything that's got an overload for those functions and harness the full power of C++11 SFINAE.

I'm running into problems with the return type, however. Here's what I tried, illustraded by generic "sum" function for numeric containers:

First, usage code:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};  
vector<int> vec(begin(arr),end(arr));
auto sum1 = sum(vec);
auto sum2 = sum(arr);
```

That's my expectation of the function - to work both from containers and arrays.

Here's my attempt at solving the problem:

```
template<typename T> auto sum(const T& container) -> decltype(*begin(container)) {
    typedef remove_const<remove_reference<decltype(*begin(container))>::type>::type val_type;
    val_type sum;
    if (is_arithmetic<val_type>::value)
        sum = 0;
    for (const auto& value: container)
        sum = sum + value;
    return sum;
}
```

**What's wrong with that:** It works, but gives out a warning (`C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary`). That's obvoiusly a bad thing, spawning undefined behavior, basically.

I tried defining the trailing return type in following ways:

**1.Copy declaration for var_type**

```
template<typename T> auto sum(const T& container) ->
    remove_const<remove_reference<decltype(*begin(container))>::type>::type
```

This spawns an error: `C2923: 'std::remove_const' : 'std::remove_reference<_Ty>::type' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'` (strange, because same works for `val_type`

**2.Use container[0]**

```
template<typename T> auto sum(const T& container) -> decltype(container[0])
```

This works, but it both spawns additional restriction on `container` type, which I'd like to avoid, and gives out `C4172` for `vector`

**3.Try to remove just reference**

```
template<typename T> auto sum(const T& container) -> remove_reference<decltype(*begin(container))>::type
```

Result: `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'type'`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it simple : `decltype(*std::begin(container))` is resolved in a `T const &`.
Apply the same operations as `val_type`, add some `typename` keywords and it'll work.

Why is typename mandatory ? Look at the errors :

```
error:   expected a type, got ‘std::remove_reference<decltype (* std::begin(container))>::type’
```

If you try just adding typename before this expresssion, you now have :

```
error: need ‘typename’ before
    ‘std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype (* std::begin(container))>::type>::type’
because
    ‘std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype (* std::begin(container))>::type>’
is a dependent scope
```

Working example with GCC 4.7.2 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
auto sum (T const & container)
-> typename remove_const<typename remove_reference<decltype(*begin(container))>::type>::type
{
    typedef typename remove_const<typename remove_reference<decltype(*begin(container))>::type>::type val_type;
    val_type sum;
    if (is_arithmetic<val_type>::value)
        sum = 0;
    for (const auto& value: container)
        sum = sum + value;
    return sum;
}

int main ()
{
    vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    cout << sum(v) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I guess I didn't really got grasp of it. `typename` solved it for good. Thank you!

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for `std::decay`, that's also very useful... How can `using` be applied in this context, though?

Comment: @darkwanderer `template<class T>using decay_t=typename std::decay<T>::type;`, and now you can `decay_t<` blah `>` with no more `typename` needed.

Comment: @Yakk despite 4 years of C++ experience - every day there's something new to it :) Cheers!

Comment: @darkwanderer so you are a novice then  ;)